# Dynamic select option Radio button

Tags: jquery

Each radio buttons upon selected has its own select options, please see my code below.

Using jQuery, please can someone help me get it working?

```
<HEAD>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $('#machines input:radio').change(function() {

      var selectedVal = $("#machines input:radio:checked").val();
      if(1 == selectedVal){
          var bikeList = '<select name="Bikes"><option>Ducati</option><option>Kawasaki</option></select>';
          $('select').remove();
          $('#selectList').append(bikeList);
      }else if(2 == selectedVal){
          var carList = '<select name="Cars"><option>Audi</option><option>Nissan</option></select>';
          $('select').remove();
          $('#selectList').append(carList);
      }

  });
</script>

</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <div id="machines">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="1" />Bikes 
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="2" />Cars
  </div>
  <div id="selectList"></div>

​</BODY>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The selected radio button will showing its corresponding dropdown box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your code within document ready handler, note that `:radio` selector is deprecated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $list = $('#selectList'); // you can cache the object for better performace
   $('#machines input[type=radio]').change(function() {
      var selectedVal = this.value; // you can use `this` which refers to the currect input
      if (1 == selectedVal) {
          var bikeList = '<select name="Bikes"><option>Ducati</option><option>Kawasaki</option></select>';
          $list.html(bikeList);
      } else if (2 == selectedVal) {
          var carList = '<select name="Cars"><option>Audi</option><option>Nissan</option></select>';
          $list.html(carList);
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are other stuff we can fix with the design. But I think it is easier to learn if I made as few changes as possible to your code to get it to work. Enjoy.

```
<HEAD>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#machines input:radio').change(function() {
      var selectedVal = $("#machines input:radio:checked").val();
      if(1 == selectedVal){
      var bikeList = '<select name="Bikes"><option>Ducati</option><option>Kawasaki</option></select>';
      $('#selectList').html(bikeList);
      }else if(2 == selectedVal){
      var carList = '<select name="Cars"><option>Audi</option><option>Nissan</option></select>';
      $('#selectList').html(carList);
      }

  });
});
</script>

</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <div id="machines">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="1" />Bikes 
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="2" />Cars
  </div>
  <div id="selectList"></div>

​</BODY>
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 // your code here
});
```

or put the script under 2 radio buttons

```
<HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <div id="machines">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="1" />Bikes 
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="2" />Cars
  </div>
  <div id="selectList"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#machines input:radio').change(function() {
      var selectedVal = $("#machines input:radio:checked").val();
      if(1 == selectedVal){
          var bikeList = '<select name="Bikes"><option>Ducati</option><option>Kawasaki</option></select>';
          $('select').remove();
          $('#selectList').append(bikeList);
      }else if(2 == selectedVal){
          var carList = '<select name="Cars"><option>Audi</option><option>Nissan</option></select>';
          $('select').remove();
          $('#selectList').append(carList);
      }
  });
</script>

​</BODY>
```